# Eclipse C++ IDE "unresolved inclusions" are unresolvable

Tags: c++, ide, eclipse-cdt

Eclipse:
Version: 2022-12 (4.26.0)
Build id: 20221201-1913

OS: Xubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Downloaded Eclipse and have been spent hours now trying to get the most basic thing to work.

All "includes" at the top of a single .h file, e.g.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
```

give "Unresolved inclusion", and of course every use of e.g. std::string throws an error thereafter.

Every mention of this that I can find is essentially given on [this Eclipse doc page](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_prop_general_pns_inc.htm) -- go into Properties for the project and specify the include paths and symbols (screenshot below). Problem is, there's no such thing, at least not in my version detailed above.

The full project that I wrote with no IDE in vim compiles beautifully with straightforward cmake/make, and so there is nothing missing from the system, and nothing is in non-standard places.

Is Eclipse a write-off, or is there something obvious that I need to do to get it working? Some listicles say "Initial setup can be time consuming" ([source](https://hackr.io/blog/cpp-ide)), but others suggest it's "easy to use" ([source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/top-5-ides-for-c-that-you-should-try-once/)). Clearly my experience is consistent with the first comment, but the fact that the second comment is out there drives me to put this question out there on the hopes of redeeming Eclipse and salvaging my time spent so far.

[image: screenshot of missing include "Paths and symbols"]

Comment: Have you created a C++ project? Are the source files named as C++ source files (ending in e.g. `.cpp`)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, yes the file was the first created within a project, and it's a .h, not .cpp. "Properties for <project>"/"C/C++ General"/"File Types" confirms this is is a legit extension for C++ header files. But I tried .hpp for what it was worth, with no joy.

Answer (score 1):

*Possibly* answering my own question, maybe it will help somebody else.

Apologies if this is naive, I'm just starting trying to use IDEs instead of DIY everything in barebones vim. Maybe I'm expecting too much of an IDE.

I loaded up the rest of the files in the project, and now it actually compiles and runs within the IDE just fine, with no particular effort to set any project properties other than having to supply the CMakeLists.txt myself.

It then recognized system libraries, and even though the build system worked fine and my code ran to console correctly, it still threw a pile of errors owing to an inability to recognise info in local .h files. I had to follow guidance [here](https://community.silabs.com/s/question/0D51M00007xeJNzSAM/indexer-not-working-properly-enable-index-source-and-header-files-opened-in-editor?language=en_US), which was to tick the box that is apparently meant to be ticked by default, but wasn't, at  -> Properties -> C/C++ General -> Indexer -> "Index source and header files opened in editor".

*Then* everything appeared to be error-free, though there seemed to be a lag in the icon indicators -- some icons persist in showing errors in files and functions that aren't there when viewing the file, and only disappear after rebuilding the code.

So insofar as it goes, the initial problem is solved. However, after then trying to get on with work and add a function prototype to a .h file, everything in the corresponding .cpp file turned to an error with "Member declaration not found". I'm concluding that Eclipse just isn't helpful enough, but leaving this here in case it helps somebody.

[image: screenshot of box to tick]

Comment: It would be tedious to have to load <ctime> <iostream> etc. into the editor for them to be indexed. You need to tell Eclipse where your compiler is. In the case of a tutorial the location is most likely on your path. I've used cross compilers which were decidedly not on the path, it takes more input from me but it's straightforward. It's been a while since I started an Eclipse CDT project. If I had done so recently I'd be answering and not commenting. I'm hoping this comment guides you to the right steps to take.

Comment: Extending my comment a bit, when Eclipse CDT knows where your compiler is, it can invoke it to find out where the standard headers are kept for that compiler.

Comment: The dialog that I used to use frequently in 2019 versions of CDT corresponds closely to [this dialog](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_prop_general_pns_inc.htm) Tool Settings tab.

Comment: @cardiffspaceman I thought too it might be a matter of locating my standard-location-compiler for the IDE, but I couldn't figure out where to specify it, and indeed it _is_ able to use it when building, so it _must_ know where it is. And in fact the standard libraries problem did resolve after a successful build. It's now the connection/linkage between local .cpp and .h that keeps breaking. Toggling the indexing option per above fixed it, but only temporarily.

Comment: The way I understand that your source could actually compile, but still display with all sorts of red squigglies, is that the parser in the editor that displays the red squigglies is not the same configuration of compiler as the one that the build uses.

Comment: Open one of your files in the Eclipse editor and use the menu command, "Project | C++ Index | Create Parser Log File" This command will generate a text file that shows exactly what the parser found from just the specific file that is in focus in the editor (e.g. main.cpp or whathaveyou).